# Como definir um header com um token JWT numa requisição feita pela biblioteca Requests?

Tags: python, http, jwt, python-requests

Estou usando a biblioteca `Requests` do Python para fazer requisições HTTP.

Consegui fazer uma requisição post tranquilamente para poder obter um token JWT. Mas agora preciso enviar esse token através de um header, porém não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.

O código que eu tenho atualmente é:

```
import requests

class Webservice(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.authData = None

    def authenticate(self, username, password):

        credentials = {
            "username" : username,
            "password" : password
        }

        response = requests.post("http://exemplo/usuario/ajax-jwt-auth", data=credentials)

        data = response.json()

        if data.token:
            #guarda o token
            self.authData = data

        return response

    def getData(self):
        #preciso passar o token por um header nessa requisição
        return requests.get("http://exemplo/api/servicos")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote [`requests-jwt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-jwt), que basicamente cria um mecanismo [customizado de autenticação](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-authentication) para que seja usado com [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Para instalar, digite no terminal:

```
pip install requests_jwt
```

<sub>**Nota**: Requerimentos: [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) e [`pyJWT`](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)</sub>

---

Você pode usá-lo assim:

```
import requests
from requests_jwt import JWTAuth

class Webservice(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authData = None

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        credentials = {
            "username" : username,
            "password" : password
        }
        # ...
        if data.token:
            #guarda o token
            self.authData = data.token

    def getData(self):
        auth = JWTAuth(self.authData)

        #preciso passar o token por um header nessa requisição
        return requests.get("http://exemplo/api/servicos", headers={'Authorization': auth})
        # Você também pode tentar usar...
        #return requests.get("http://exemplo/api/servicos", auth=auth)
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta publicada resolve bem o problemas, mas apenas como acréscimo gostaria de dizer que é possível também fazer a utilização do JWT sem instalar uma biblioteca.

Basta definir um `header` `"Authorization"` com o valor `"Bearer token_aqui"`.

Veja:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer %s" % token
}

return requests.get("http://example.com/api/results", headers=headers)
```